# WSL2でshでmkdirがパーミッション不足でできない

Tags: linux, bash, wsl

WSL2上でフォルダ作成するシェルスクリプトを書いているのですが、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいできません。

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/username/hoge/data’: Permission denied
```

スクリプトは以下のとおりです。

```
read NAME
dir_path="/home/username"
mkdir -p ${dir_path}/${NAME}/data/output
mkdir -p ${dir_path}/${NAME}/features
```

`home/username`はusernameに権限がついているのも確認済みなのですが。。

Linux初心者ですので、よろしくお願いいたします。

**追記**
権限ですが、
`drwxr-xr-x  9 username   username   4096 Nov 14 10:07 username`
でした。
2~4文字目が全部権限がついているので大丈夫という認識でした。

また、`username`上で`mkdir test`をするとフォルダ作成できました。
絶対パスでの指定がまずいのでしょうか。

Comment: `/home/username/hoge/` ディレクトリのパーミッションはどの様になっていますか？

Comment: /home と /home/username のパーミッションはどうなっていますか？　「usernameに権限がついているのも確認済み」と書かれていますが、どんなパーミッションがついているのか判りません。　何を確認されたのでしょうか？

Comment: @metropolis さま hogeは作成されていません。-pで一気に作成できるという認識でしたが誤りでしょうか。。

Comment: @user87562 はい、一気に作成できるのですが、可能性としてスクリプトの実行以前に `hoge` ディレクトリが既に存在しているのではないだろうか？と思った次第です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hogeを作成時点でデフォルトパーミッションでhogeディレクトリ作成されます。※親の権限は引き継ぎません。
そのデフォルトパーミッション的にhogeの下に子ディレクトリ作成できなくなっていないでしょうか？
shの実行者がusernameなのかも気になります。
１度hogeまで作成するshに変えて実行してみて、作成された/home/username/hogeの権限を確認してみてはいかがでしょう。